# PageRank in Python: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, recursion, social-networking, pagerank

I have a dataset - around 30000 users and I want to calculate an influence of each user based on UserRank algorithm, which is based on PageRank:
[image]

For each user I have a list of followers. I tried to calculate it in Python, but I'm getting:

`RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`

Here's the code:

```py
def calculate_user_rank(user_id):
    user_rank = 0
    for j in user[user_id]["followers"]:
        user_rank += (1 + (user[user_id]["followers_count"]/user[user_id]["tweets"]) * calculate_user_rank(j))/user[j]["followers_count"]
    return user_rank
```

Is there any way how to calculate this measure for each user?

Comment: can u try an iterative solution

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show your code?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma the code is above

Answer (score 0):

One way to deal with the problem is to utilise the concepts of dynamic programming, because you might be repetitively solving same sub-problem over and over. So, its better to store the result of the page ranks of user rather than calculating them again and again.

Use:

```
def calculate_user_rank(user_id, memo={}):
    user_rank = 0
    for j in user[user_id]["followers"]:
        if j not in memo:
            memo[j] = calculate_user_rank(j, memo)

        user_rank += (1 + (user[user_id]["followers_count"]/user[user_id]["tweets"]) * memo[j])/user[j]["followers_count"]
    memo[user_id] = user_rank

    return memo[user_id]
```

Comment: @Yakimget What's the problem?

Comment: "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded" again. I've sent you an email with user dictionary attached, so you can check your solution

Comment: @Yakimget didn't receive the mail.

Comment: @Yakimget Got your mail, i have inspected it, and found out that there are follower id's for a particular user for which the corresponding user doesn't exists for e.g if `user_id = 11` then there is no user with `followerid = 9`

Comment: I fixed it, but again I'm getting RecursionError

Answer (score 0):

You can always change the default recursion limit: [What is the maximum recursion depth in Python, and how to increase it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323001/what-is-the-maximum-recursion-depth-in-python-and-how-to-increase-it)
But in this example I would prefer iterative solution for your problem (like here: https://github.com/thomasjhuang/PageRank/blob/master/run_pagerank.py) and cache for each user his score for performance.